# How are patricia trees used to prove the balance of an account?

Tags: accounts, balances, merkle-patricia-tries

I understand how merkle trees are used to prove the balance of an address with a small subset of the blockchain. On the Ethereum case, though, the result of a transaction could depend on the final state of a contract, which could depend on all transactions ever sent to it. How can you be able to prove the balance of an account while at the same time ignoring all transactions that modified the state of a contract that sent Ether to that account?